# Excel Long format subtract previous row in certain condition

Tags: excel, subtraction, long-format-data

I have an Excel Long format with the same ID over several days. Participants answered different types of questionnaires and times were recorded. I want to calculate the difference between two types of questionnaires (AE-AB), so that it looks like this:

```
  N    Q
```

day form  time    difference
1    **AB   8:00**        8,00
1    AT   8:15
1    **AE   16:00**
2    **AB   8:30**        7,30
2    AT   8:33
2    **AE   16:00**
3   **AB   9:00**        8,00
3    AT   16:00
3    **AE   17:00**

There are several "form" types between AB & AE (e.g. AT) that are not of interest.
I guess I need to create an "if"statement (if Nx = AE;..) then take the time of that row (IF Nx = AE; Qx - ...) and then find the matching row of AB that was the most recent before AE and match the corresponding time of that row to subtract it)

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Your question is not clear, please edit the question and show the VBA code you have tried if this is what you have done. Add the VBA tag if so.

Comment: Welcome Rebecca! Read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!